Stylelint doesn't highlight missing modules in VSCode - Sass
The picture shows essentially what the issue is. Stylelint will highlight errors, such as too much whitespace or duplicated properties, however if a module is not imported, then it will not highlight anything. I can only see it in the terminal, where it fails to compile.
.stylelintrc
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard-scss"],
  "plugins": ["stylelint-scss"],
  "rules": {
    "at-rule-no-unknown": null,
    "block-no-empty": true,
    "color-hex-length": "long",
    "color-no-invalid-hex": true,
    "comment-no-empty": true,
    "declaration-block-no-duplicate-properties": [
      true,
      {
        "ignore": ["consecutive-duplicates-with-different-values"]
      }
    ],
    "declaration-block-no-redundant-longhand-properties": [
      true,
      {
        "ignoreShorthands": ["/flex/", "/grid/"]
      }
    ],
    "declaration-block-no-shorthand-property-overrides": true,
    "declaration-block-single-line-max-declarations": 1,
    "font-family-name-quotes": "always-where-required",
    "font-family-no-duplicate-names": true,
    "font-family-no-missing-generic-family-keyword": true,
    "function-calc-no-unspaced-operator": true,
    "function-linear-gradient-no-nonstandard-direction": true,
    "keyframe-declaration-no-important": true,
    "media-feature-name-no-unknown": true,
    "media-feature-name-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "no-descending-specificity": null,
    "no-duplicate-at-import-rules": true,
    "no-duplicate-selectors": true,
    "no-empty-source": null,

    "no-invalid-double-slash-comments": true,
    "no-unknown-animations": true,
    "property-no-unknown": true,
    "property-no-vendor-prefix": true,
    "scss/at-mixin-argumentless-call-parentheses": "always",
    "scss/at-rule-no-unknown": true,
    "scss/media-feature-value-dollar-variable": "always",
    "scss/no-duplicate-dollar-variables": true,
    "scss/selector-no-redundant-nesting-selector": true,
    "scss/operator-no-newline-after": true,
    "scss/operator-no-newline-before": true,
    "scss/operator-no-unspaced": true,
    "selector-class-pattern": "^[a-z0-9_-]+$",
    "selector-id-pattern": "^[a-z0-9_-]+$",
    "selector-max-compound-selectors": 5,
    "selector-max-universal": 1,
    "selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown": true,
    "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": [true, { "ignorePseudoElements": ["ng-deep"] }],
    "selector-type-case": "lower",
    "selector-type-no-unknown": [
      true,
      {
        "ignoreTypes": ["/^ui-view/", "/^ag-/", "/^app-/", "/^ng-select/"]
      }
    ],
    "string-no-newline": true,
    "unit-no-unknown": [
      true,
      {
        "ignoreFunctions": "image-set"
      }
    ],
    "value-no-vendor-prefix": true
  }
}


Stylelint Package Versions:
    "stylelint": "16.9.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "14.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "36.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "13.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "6.7.0",



It's not stylelint's job to highlight compile errors
